# How can i manually clear facebook session in my site when I logout from my site

Tags: facebook, cakephp

I have integrated facebook in my cakephp site.. I check for facebook session in before-filter and I have added code to redirect to myaccount page together with the facebook-code created for generating access token. My problem is even after I log out I could get facebook id  with $this->connect->user('id') , ie the session exists. So it goes to facebook login page , since I have requested to fetch facebook-code, if facebook session exists . I tried to clear session using $this->Session->delete('FB'); and $this->Session->delete('FB.Me');but no use..pls help

Comment: Need more information. Does `$this->Session->delete();` work for other things? What does `debug($this->Session->read());` output? Also, is the code for `$this->connect->user()` publicly available? If you don't need to keep *any* session data you can also use `$this->Session->destroy()`.

Comment: $this->Session->delete(); works for other cakephp sessions.Tried $this->Session->destroy(); but no use

Answer (score 0):

Mark:

The problem is your logout button needs to be different when the user is logged into Facebook. Here is an example from my web application using the Facebook plugin from Webtechnick (this example works properly):

```
                    $logoutLink = '';
                    if (empty($facebookUser)) {
                            $logoutLink = $this->Html->link(
                                    $this->Html->tag('span', __('Logout', true)),
                                    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'),
                                    array('escape' => false)
                            );
                    } else {
                            $logoutLink = $this->Facebook->logout(array(
                                'redirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'),
                                'label' => __('Logout', true))
                            );
                    }
                    echo $logoutLink;
```